# На что влияет наличие спецификатора const при определении функции?

Tags: c++

Возвращая ссылку на объект, спецификатор const запретит изменять объект:

```
const int& foo()
{ ... }

int main ()
{
    foo=5; //error: assignment of read-only location ‘f()’
    return 0;
}
```

Но чем будет отличаться const int foo() от int foo()? Речь идет о функциях НЕ членах классов.

И правильно ли я понимаю, что функцию, которая возвращает ссылку, можно использовать как lvalue?:

```
int& foo()
{ ... }

int bar()
{ ... }

int main ()
{
    foo=5; //OK
    bar=5; //error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Скобочки потерялись в main?

Comment: В вопросе `Но чем будет отличаться const int foo()` может вы имели в виду `const int & foo()` ?

Comment: @Cerbo Нет, я всё правильно написал. Какая разница, вернет функция const int или int, если вернувшееся значение всё равно нельзя менять - вот суть моего вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но чем будет отличаться const int foo() от int foo()?

`const int foo()` от `int foo()` не отличается почти ничем. Различия могут проявиться лишь в особо хитрых случаях разрешения перегрузки функций - но эти случаи никому не интересны.

> Речь идет о функциях НЕ членах классов.

Даже если функции - члены классов (т.е. *методы*) - то все равно они ничем не отличаются.

> И правильно ли я понимаю, что функцию, которая возвращает ссылку, можно использовать как lvalue?

**Значение** функции, которая возвращает ссылку, можно использовать как `lvalue`:

```
int& foo()
{ ... }

int bar()
{ ... }

int main ()
{
    foo()=5; //OK
    bar()=5; //error
    return 0;
}
```